# Filtering values using a common key in a SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server

I have two different tables with multiple columns. Like the following

Table 1

```
ID Name Age
12   x    24
13   y    44
14   z    55
```

Table 2

```
ID  Sex  
12   M   
13   f   
14   M
```

Only common point is the ID here. How can filter the value of table 2 using the common key? Do I have to join the tables? Is there any other way without repeating the values?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID` ... it doesn't get any easier than this.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks man. It helped. if you post it as an answer, will be useful for others in future.